# Grails 3 create-app Command Failing

Tags: windows, grails, installation

I am trying to set up Grails 3.2.6 on Windows 7 Pro, using Java JDK 8. Grails seems to be set up properly as I can do `C:\>grails -version` and get output from it.

The problem is, when I try to create an app, I get a connection timeout. After Googling for a solution, I haven't found one yet. This is the verbose stacktrace:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Error |
Error occurred running Grails CLI: connect timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:341)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:317)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:299)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:291)
    at org.grails.cli.boot.GrailsDependencyVersions.<init>(GrailsDependencyVersions.groovy:53)
    at org.grails.cli.boot.GrailsDependencyVersions.<init>(GrailsDependencyVersions.groovy:49)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.repository.MavenProfileRepository.<init>(MavenProfileRepository.groovy:53)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.createMavenProfileRepository(GrailsCli.groovy:333)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:234)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)

Error |
Error occurred running Grails CLI: connect timed out
```

I have tried so far:

- Running CMD as Administrator
- Disabling Windows Firewall
- Moving Grails to my user directory rather than C:\
- Placed a settings.groovy file in USER_HOME\Grails\grails-3.2.6 pointing to my repo (settings below).

**settings.groovy**:

```
grails {
   profiles {
       repositories {
           myRepo {
              url = "http://example.com"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I have also successfully installed Grails 3.2.6 on a Linux virtual machine on the same Windows computer through the same network (bridged adapter settings), as well as a separate laptop running Windows 7, but I need to get this running on my main development computer rather than a virtual machine or personal laptop.

Comment: have you check, how good is your internet connections? because first-time installs and runs Grails will get huge downloads library.

Comment: The internet connection should be fine - I'm doing this in an office environment and others have been able to set this up without an issue. As mentioned in the OP, I've also been able to set it up on a Linux virtual machine on the same network. The connection doesn't drop when I do this on my workstation.